# Change page title dynamically with tag manager

Tags: google-ads-api, google-tag-manager

I need to change page title dynamically with tag manager, it must be like the search query from google.

For example if I search in Google (organic and paid): **Hotel Toronto**

And the title must be: **Hotel Toronto**

Do you have any idea on how I can do it?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can change the page title by creating a custom HTML tag and set the title property

```
<script>
document.title = "I am title hear me roar";
</script>
```

Set the trigger to "Pageview->All Pageviews".

However I doubt that even with the latest changes in the way Google evaluates javascript in pages it will evaluate a title that's been changed via Javascript. That does need to stop you from trying, but the chances of success are slim.